# react-intl FormattedMessage

Tags: javascript, react-intl, formatted

I'm using the react-intl library in my app, and I'm encountering an issue where letters inside parentheses () are being capitalized in my FormattedMessage component.

For example, if I define the defaultMessage prop as follows:

```
<FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Please select the desired option(s) from the list below." />
```

The letter "s" inside the parentheses is being capitalized as "S" on certain devices or browsers, but not others. I've checked my CSS and font settings, and confirmed that they are not causing the issue.

Any insights into why this issue might be occurring, and how I could prevent the capitalization of letters inside parentheses would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Any insights into why this issue might be occurring, and how I could prevent the capitalization of letters inside parentheses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont know the `FormattedMessage` tool, but have you tried escaping the parentheses?  `option\(s\)`

Answer (score 1):

intl.formattedMessage does not automatically capitalize every new word in a string, check your css styles

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).